# Youtube Comment API: Comment Insert 403 forbidden insufficient permissions

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

This is what im using to add comments to youtube :

```
gapi.client.youtube.commentThreads.insert({
          part: "snippet", commentData
        }).then(function (response) {
          console.log("response", response);
    })
```

This is what im getting while hit that :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undocumented function - gapi.client.youtube.commentThreads.insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533800/undocumented-function-gapi-client-youtube-commentthreads-insert)

Answer (score 2):

> Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Means exactly that the currently authenticated user has not granted you the permissions to do that.

If you check the documentation [comments.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) you will see that in order to use this method you must have authncated your user with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl` scope

[image]

Comment: is HTTPS is Required ?

Comment: For authorization of course you cant login to an authentication server without HTTPS that would be a security nightmare.

Comment: I fixed it . I using  Gapi for insert comment